# Converter formato parecido com xml para json com javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, xml

Estou utilizando o seguinte código para fazer a leitura de um arquivo similar a um XML, porém preciso que esse arquivo seja convertido para um JSON, será que alguem consegue me dar esse auxílio ?
Segue o código da minha index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var openFile = function(event) {
            var input = event.target;

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function() {
                var text = reader.result;
                var node = document.getElementById('output');
                node.innerText = text;
                console.log(reader.result.substring(0, 200));

                var xml, parser, xmlDoc;

                parser = new DOMParser();
                xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
                xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("children")[0].childNodes.forEach(function(value) {
                    console.log(value.id);
                });


            };

            reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
    <div id='output'>
        ...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

O arquivo está escrito da seguinte forma em um arquivo chamado child.txt:

```html
<item  name='MenuPrincipal' label='Menu Principal' >
    <children>
        <child id='child1' />
        <child id='child2'/>
        <child id='child3'/>
        <child id='child4'/>        
    </children>
</item>
```

Preciso converter esse arquivo de modo que me seja gerado um Json.
Alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu posso fazer essa mágica ?kk
Obrigado.

Comment: Pra mim isso é sim XML, não vejo nada que diga o contrário, tanto é um XML que você até usou `DOMParser`.

Comment: Certo, o visual dele aparenta ser um xml mas é uma linguagem própria, baseado no xml, mas não consigo converter esse arquivo pra json direto, bom pelo menos eu não consegui, se tiver alguma sugestão estou aberto a tentar.

Comment: E qual o resultado que você quer? `{"item":[{"children": ["child1", "child2", "child3", "child4"]}]}`?

Comment: exato eu gostaria de conseguir o retorno dos id's do child.

Comment: @TonyMontana se tiver alguma sugestão agradeço.

Comment: XML é uma linguagem sem padrão no nome das tags, você pode criar seu XML com qualquer tag que quiser inventar, criar uma tag ou atributo proprio para um elemento não a torna uma nova linguagem.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu entendi, mas vou detalhar mais: a real extensão desse arquivo é ITD, e não XML por isso preciso ler ele como txt porque apesar de ser identico a um xml a estrutura é diferente e não tem conversor de itd pra json hehe.

Comment: Extensão sendo .xml, .itd, .foienaovoltou não interferem no conteudo, isso é apenas para facilitar programas Desktop a identificarem o tipo do documento sem ter que ler, você pode inventar sua propria extensão e ainda sim será xml. Tem muitos arquivos que tem extensões proprias como .manifest e web.conf (IIS) que na verdade são arquivos XML padronizados para um uso especifico, então o que você tem é um arquivo XML padronizado para este tal ITD. Como eu já disse XML é um documento customizavel, não quer dizer que pq é customizado que deixa de ser XML.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento po valeu cara, sinceramente não sabia disso rsrs sou novo ainda na programação mas valeu a explicação, vou editar o tópico.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui encontrar uma solução completa para o meu problema.

Segue o código da index.html:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Example external File with XML to JSON</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="xml2json.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        h4 {
            position: relative;
            margin: 2px auto;
            text-align: left;
        }
        
        #jsnstr {
            margin: .35em .4em 1em 2em;
            max-height: 500px;
            background: #ffc;
            border: 1px solid #dadada;
            padding: .4em .5em;
            color: #333;
            font-weight: 800;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Result JSON</h4>
    <pre id="jsnstr"></pre>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="xml2json.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[
        // gets the JSON string from a file with XML content ("test.xml")
        var jsonstr = xml2json.fromFile('test.xml', 'string');

        // adds the JSON string in HTML element with id="jsnstr"
        document.getElementById('jsnstr').innerHTML = jsonstr;
        // ]]>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Segue o código do arquivo xml2json.js:

```js
// Converts XML to JSON
// from: http://coursesweb.net/javascript/convert-xml-json-javascript_s2
function XMLtoJSON() {
    var me = this; // stores the object instantce

    // gets the content of an xml file and returns it in 
    me.fromFile = function(xml, rstr) {
        // Cretes a instantce of XMLHttpRequest object
        var xhttp = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        // sets and sends the request for calling "xml"
        xhttp.open("GET", xml, false);
        xhttp.send(null);

        // gets the JSON string
        var json_str = jsontoStr(setJsonObj(xhttp.responseXML));

        // sets and returns the JSON object, if "rstr" undefined (not passed), else, returns JSON string
        return (typeof(rstr) == 'undefined') ? JSON.parse(json_str) : json_str;
    }

    // returns XML DOM from string with xml content
    me.fromStr = function(xml, rstr) {
        // for non IE browsers
        if (window.DOMParser) {
            var getxml = new DOMParser();
            var xmlDoc = getxml.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
        } else {
            // for Internet Explorer
            var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async = "false";
        }

        // gets the JSON string
        var json_str = jsontoStr(setJsonObj(xmlDoc));

        // sets and returns the JSON object, if "rstr" undefined (not passed), else, returns JSON string
        return (typeof(rstr) == 'undefined') ? JSON.parse(json_str) : json_str;
    }

    // receives XML DOM object, returns converted JSON object
    var setJsonObj = function(xml) {
        var js_obj = {};
        if (xml.nodeType == 1) {
            if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
                js_obj["@attributes"] = {};
                for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                    var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                    js_obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.value;
                }
            }
        } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) {
            js_obj = xml.nodeValue;
        }
        if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
            for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
                var nodeName = item.nodeName;
                if (typeof(js_obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                    js_obj[nodeName] = setJsonObj(item);
                } else {
                    if (typeof(js_obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                        var old = js_obj[nodeName];
                        js_obj[nodeName] = [];
                        js_obj[nodeName].push(old);
                    }
                    js_obj[nodeName].push(setJsonObj(item));
                }
            }
        }
        return js_obj;
    }

    // converts JSON object to string (human readablle).
    // Removes '\t\r\n', rows with multiples '""', multiple empty rows, '  "",', and "  ",; replace empty [] with ""
    var jsontoStr = function(js_obj) {
        var rejsn = JSON.stringify(js_obj, undefined, 2).replace(/(\\t|\\r|\\n)/g, '').replace(/"",[\n\t\r\s]+""[,]*/g, '').replace(/(\n[\t\s\r]*\n)/g, '').replace(/[\s\t]{2,}""[,]{0,1}/g, '').replace(/"[\s\t]{1,}"[,]{0,1}/g, '').replace(/\[[\t\s]*\]/g, '""');
        return (rejsn.indexOf('"parsererror": {') == -1) ? rejsn : 'Invalid XML format';
    }
};

// creates object instantce of XMLtoJSON
var xml2json = new XMLtoJSON();
```

Pra que seja mostrado um resultado de fato basta criar um arquivo chamado "test.xml" e inserir as informações do xml lá dentro.

Agradeço a todos que esclareceram minhas dúvidas e principalmente o @GuilhermeNascimento, pois graças aos seus esclarecimentos consegui encontrar uma solução mais adequada a minha necessidade.